Is there any evidence that 八 used to be pronounced bia?
I've heard from someone that 八 was at one point pronounced bia1 in old Mandarin. The topic came up when discussing the term biaji, a word for chewing loudly. I couldn't find any evidence for it, since the -j- is not present in any other Sinitic languages that I know of or in Middle Chinese reconstructions.

Possibly, but "old Mandarin" is rather vague. The fact that the financial phonetic loan is spelt 捌 lends some credence to the idea.


Hope this is what you need. Actually “Bia Ji” still popular in spoken language, but the standard Chinese uses “Ba Ji” 叭叽。

I think the word you are looking for is "吧唧(biaji/baiji)", which is pronounced as [bā jī]. One of its meanings is "open and close one's lips that make a loud, disturbing sound while eating". It has nothing to do with 八 except the shared sound [bā].

In some places, such as my hometown Jinhua, 八 was indeed pronounced bia in ancient times. And in Jinhua dialect, the pronunciation of 八 is still bia.

这是一个有趣的话题。身为汉语母语人士，我可以为您清晰解答。我们口语中所谓“bia ji”其实正确的读音是“ba ji”，写作“吧唧”。在中国某些地方的方言中（不知道你们是否能理解方言的意思，方言就是指在中国不同地方生活的人演化出了不同读法的汉语。虽然后来普通话大范围普及，但是这些方言的印记还在）“吧唧”读作“bia ji”。这确实无法在相关典籍中找到，因为“bia”并不是一个普通话认可的读音，它所指代的汉字就是“吧唧”的“吧”，我们就可以将“bia”写作“吧”。
It's an interesting topic. As a native Chinese speaker, I can give you a clear answer. What we call "bia ji" in colloquial language is actually "ba ji", which is written as "吧唧". In dialects in some parts of China (I don't know if you understand dialects, but dialects are Chinese that people living in different parts of China have evolved to read differently. Although Mandarin was later widely used, the imprint of these dialects remains) "吧唧" is pronounced as "bia ji". This really can not be found in the relevant classics, because "bia" is not a Putonghua recognized pronunciation, it refers to the Chinese character is "吧", we can write "bia" as "吧".
